Can make call, accept it but can not invite the user from same tenant to the call, using Teams Bot and Graph API
Project: Developed on .NET 4.8
Microsoft.Graph.Communications.Calls: 1.2.0.10563
Microsoft.Graph: 5.38.0
if there is an incoming call, it fails if I want to add a user from the same tenant to:
call.Participants.InviteAsync() 

or
_botCall.TransferAsync() 

It gives the following error:

Request authorization tenant mismatch

Tenant Id of call is empty or does not match the one passed in

I have the bot registered as multi tenant, the same bot:

Can read users from the tenant.
Can make a call from the bot to the user of the tenant.

